# Vue 3 Composition API - Disabling form submit button until all conditions are met

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to disable my form submit button until all the input fields are filled in and there are no errors.

```
<button
  :disabled="disabled"
  type="submit"
  value="Submit"
  >
  Suggest
</button>

let disabled = ref(true);
let error = ref(false);

nextTick(() => {
  let inputs = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("form__input"));
  if (!error.value) {
    inputs.forEach((input) => {
      if (input.value === "") {
        disabled.value = true;
      } else {
        disabled.value = false;
      }
    });
  }
})
```

The button is disabled by default but it won't 'enable' itself once the already mentioned conditions are met.

So far, I'm using a helper lifecycle hook `nextTick()` which clearly doesn't help me in this situation.

The 'disabled' state will update in the console but not on the DOM.

How can I approach this?

Cheers

Comment: `disabled` will be false only when the last `input` has a value other than `""` - as written, however, that `inputs.forEach` is run exactly once - and never run again regardless of your input values ... so there's two issues ... 1. Only the last input determines the state of disabled, and 2. you only ever test the inputs once, before you've had a chance to even input anything

Comment: also, if you're using DOM methods like `document.getElementsByClassName` in vue, you're using vue wrong

Comment: @Bravo I know why the number 2 problem exists but I don't know any way to check the condition once all the inputs have been filled. Also, can you explain why using ```document.getElementsByClassName``` in Vue is wrong?

Comment: maybe "wrong" is too strong a word, but I've only never used DOM methods in Vue for obscure things like `IntersectionObserver` for popping up a scroll to top button for example ... never for getting values from inputs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is by using a `computed` value to set the disabled state of the button - based on the input values - if any are empty, button is disabled

Here's a basic example

```js
const { ref, createApp, computed } = Vue;
createApp({
    setup() {
        const input1 = ref("");
        const input2 = ref("");
        const input3 = ref("");
        // disabled is true if ANY input is empty string
        const disabled = computed(() => !input1.value || !input2.value || !input3.value);
        const clicked = () => console.log('clicked');
        return { input1, input2, input3, disabled, clicked };
    }
}).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.37/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Input 1: <input v-model="input1" type="text"/><br/>
  Input 2: <input v-model="input2" type="text"/><br/>
  Input 3: <input v-model="input3" type="text"/><br/>
  <button :disabled="disabled" @click="clicked">Click me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use `v-model`,`computed` or `@input` to listen event and change button disable status.

Comment: shouldn't that be `@change` not `@input`? but even then, shouldn't need that if you use a `computed` when the inputs are "wired" right